# What simple DB-solution do I use to extract my parsed variables from eclipse to a DB

Tags: java, database, eclipse, parsing

I tested some parsing and have the strings as a result. 
Now I want to write it to a local Database to see if i can generally do that later on a bigger scale. What Database do I choose, that is easy to handle? What are the first steps?

/edit. I work with eclipse. And I'm quite new to programming. Installed MS SQL Express, but I somehow can't handle it. Don't know where to start...

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL Database.

1) Download [mysql connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html) and add jar to your project.

2) Create a table in db and use this table to insert your values there.

java code for database

```
public class Database {
    private Connection connection = null;
    private Statement statement = null;
    private String serverName = null;
    private String dbName = null;
    private String  dbtablename = null;
    private String username = null;
    private String password = null;

   public Database() {
        serverName = //your value;
        dbName = your value
        dbtablename = //your value
        username = //your value
        password = //your value
    }

   public Connection OpenConnectionDB() {
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + dbName + "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&" + "user=" + username + "&password=" + password);
            System.out.println("conection: " + connection);
            //            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + dbName  +"?user=" + username + "&password=" + password );
            //System.out.println("debug: Connect to dbServer");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return connection;
    }

    public void closeConnectionDB() {
        if (this.connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
                connection = null;
                //System.out.println("debug: Close dbServer");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("debug: Closing Database... FAILED (NOT RUNNING)");
                Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void insert(){
         String query = //your insert query
         OpenConnectionDB();
         try {
            this.statement = this.connection.createStatement();
                this.statement.execute(query);
                statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        closeConnectionDB();
    }

   public String getResults(){
        String query = //select query
        OpenConnectionDB();
        try {
            this.statement = this.connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet  rs = this.statement.executeQuery(query);

            if(rs!=null){
                while(rs.next()){
                    return rs.getString("Your_field_name_in_db"); //get your 
                }            
            }

             statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        closeConnectionDB();
        return null;
    }


}
```

**EDIT**
Also you can use [MySQL WorkBench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to handle your database.