# JDBC How can I use a place holder in a prepared statement with a where clause?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm having a hard time understanding why this wont work, if I type the exact same thing straight into a MySQL console it accepts it but when ever I try to run it, it reports a syntax error.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '6'' at line 1

All I'm trying to do is receive the data in the row with the member_id value of whatever the user inputs. For testing purposes the value is always 6, I have tried parsing it as int instead of a string, which gave the same error, and I tried just adding the ID variable onto the end of the string instead of using a place holder but it didn't like that much either.

Here is the code:

```
public class MemberDAO {

public PreparedStatement ps = null;
public Connection dbConnection = null;

public List<Member> getMembersDetails(String ID) throws SQLException{

    List<Member> membersDetails = new ArrayList();

    String getMembershipDetails = "SELECT first_name, last_name, phone_number, email, over_18, date_joined, date_expire, fines FROM members"
            + "WHERE member_id = ?";

    try {
        DBConnection mc = new DBConnection();
        dbConnection = mc.getConnection();
        ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement(getMembershipDetails);

        ps.setString(1, ID);
        ps.executeQuery();

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(getMembershipDetails);


        String firstName = rs.getString("first_name");
        String lastName = rs.getString("last_name");
        String phoneNumber = rs.getString("phone_number");
        String email = rs.getString("email");
        String over18 = rs.getString("over_18");
        String dateJoined = rs.getString("date_joined");
        String dateExpired = rs.getString("date_expire");
        String fines = rs.getString("fines");

        Member m;
        m = new Member(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, email, over18, dateJoined, dateExpired, fines);
        membersDetails.add(m);


    }  catch (SQLException ex){
        System.err.println(ex);
        System.out.println("Failed to get Membership Details.");
        return null;
    } finally{
        if (ps != null){
            ps.close();
        }
        if (dbConnection != null){
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    } return membersDetails;
}
```

This is what's calling it:

```
private void btnChangeCustomerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  

    customerID = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Customer ID.");

    MemberDAO member = new MemberDAO();
    try {
        List membersDetails = member.getMembersDetails(customerID);

        txtFullName.setText(membersDetails.get(0) + " " + membersDetails.get(1));
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        System.out.println("Failed to get Details.");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to retrieve data.");
    }
}
```

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: why you don't create your sql query in  String getMembershipDetails = "SELECT first_name, last_name, phone_number, email, over_18, date_joined, date_expire, fines FROM members"
            + "WHERE member_id = ?";

Comment: Just another thing, the way you set txtFullName does not make much sense as you are assuming you'll get two rows back from your query...

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking Jimmy. Beny, the first_name and last_name have to be filled, and will be added to the array as the first and second entry so membersDetails.get(0) and membersDetails.get(1) should get the compulsory first and last name entries?

Comment: I used prepareStatement instead of createStatement because I was told you need to use a prepare statement if you want to use palceholders, also I did close the statement and the connection.

Comment: @fost memberDetails contains a list of Members, so memberDetails.get(0) will return the first member, .get(1) the second member...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query is:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, phone_number, email, over_18, date_joined, date_expire, fines FROM 

members WHERE member_id = ?
```

So between member and where you need a blank character

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, phone_number, email, over_18, date_joined, date_expire, fines FROM members WHERE member_id = ?
```

Comment: LOL, that's embarrasing, been up too long. Getting this error now "java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set" so a new search begins. But at least we've made progress, ty.

Comment: In your code I can't see createstatment(). Also you must close statement and Db connection! You can see my answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826029/what-simple-db-solution-do-i-use-to-extract-my-parsed-variables-from-eclipse-to/24826365#24826365
Good luck!

Comment: @Jimmysnn are you SERIOUSLY recommending to use string concatenation instead of placeholder parameters? That's a SQL injection! An horrible piece of advice!

Answer (score 1):

Your query is missing a space:

```
...fines FROM members"
        + "WHERE...
```

Will result in

```
 FROM membersWHERE
```

Which is invalid SQL

Change it to

```
 + " WHERE....
```